Unity. Использование New Input System и UI
Всем привет!
Начал делать проект в Unity. Вопрос в том как правильно обрабатывать тап по UI button на Androind?
Смысл в том что у меня есть event, который срабатывает при тапе по экрану. На сцене есть счётчик который считает тапы по экрану +1Damage (условный кликер). Рядом висит Button, эта кнопка должна отвечать за какие-то действия, например: нажимая на кнопку покупаешь какой-то баф.
Проблема в том когда тапаешь по кнопке, так же срабатывает и event тапа по экрану который добавляет +1Damage. Как определять тапнул ты по экрану или по кнопке? Пробовал метод IsPointerOverGameObject(), он вроде срабатывает, но выдаёт не критическую ошибку о том что его нужно использовать в методе Update, мне это не подходит. Можете подсказать возможные решения проблемы?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Я решил эту проблему следующим образом:
При нажатии на экран нужно проверить попадает ли луч в точке нажатия на UI элемент. За это у меня отвечает следующая функция:
//// проверка нажатия на UI элементы
private bool IsPointerOverUIObject(){
    
    // проверка на идиота
    if( EventSystem.current == null ){
        
        Debug.LogError("ВЫ НЕ ДОБАВИЛИ EventSystem на сцену, добавте её!!!");
    }
    
    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z);
    
    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
        
    return results.Count > 0;
}

Функция проверяет и если нажатие произошло на UI элемент вернёт TRUE, если вернёт FALSE можно выполнять твой код +1Damage.
Когда будешь обрабатывать нажатие вызови эту функцию и проверь есть ли UI элемент ( твоя кнопка или любая другая ) в точке нажатия:
// если точка на UI элементе то не выполняем действие
if( !IsPointerOverUIObject() ){
    
    // твой код +1Damage исполнится т.к. это не UI элемент
        
}
else{
    
    // Действие не будет выполнено т.к. нажатие на UI элемент;

}


Что-то подобное я и хотел сделать...

Но вариант Yaroslav, то же рассмотри, он хоть и чудак на букву м (зачем минусить-то), но дело говорит. Мой метод хорошо подходит для 3D проектов, описанный им для 2D.

Это не я минусил), я хотел плюс поставить а мне написало что я пока что не могу ставить оценки, что-то то в этом духе), вот и я создаю в 3D, просто с этим nis непонятно как работать, и посмотреть даже не где, хоть бы проекты публичные были какие-то на github

Aliaksandr, я знаю что не вы, это Yaroslav заминусил. В его мире есть только 2D и только его методы, всё остально ене правильно и надо жестоко карать за иное мнение. Сам при этом ничего конкретного таки не ответил. Человеку нужен конкретный рабочий пример, но делать его долго, проще обозвать меня неприятными словами и написать какой я не правильный. К сожалению мир создания игр это боль курения мануалов, без этого тут никак, а с нашим комьюнити и подавно. Вместо того что бы приводить подробный пример будут грызть друг друга.

Попробовав многие варианты, случайно узнал о статическом методе:
public static bool  RectangleContainsScreenPoint(RectTransform rect, Vector2 screenPoint, Camera cam); 

Он-то меня и выручил!
Он отлично подходит для 3D-проектов, и не так сильно нагружает систему, как при использовании GraphicRaycaster. Про минусы почитаете уже сами!

EventSystem вообще не нужно использовать напрямую!
Подобно тому, как у тебя есть объект Button, должен быть объект для клика растянутый на весь экран, который обрабатывает реакцию на клик. Если под кликом находятся сразу несколько элементов, то обработан будет тот, кто выше в иерархии канваса, то есть тот, кто отрисовывается поверх.
Является ли объект, целью обработчики EventSystem определяет флаг RaycastTarget, который можно увидеть у Image и Text. Если у дочернего Image стоит флаг RaycastTarget, то и компоненты на родительском объекте обрабатываются, как это происходит с той-же Button, где клик на самом деле происходит по Image или Text и без них Button не работает.
Класс Button обрабатывает событие клика реализуя интерфейс IPointerClickHandler, но он срабатывает при отжатии. Если нужно события касания, то необходимо написать компонент реализующий IPointerDownHandler.
И нет нужды в никаких проверках, тот ли это ёжик и не являешься ли ты жирафом, или другая чушь, которой этот объект заниматься вообще не должен, потому что, его ответственность. Это только реакция на событие и ничего более. Кто и как это событие обрабатывает, не его собачье дело, а занимается этим тот самый EventSystem, вопросов к которому у нас быть не должно.

Понял! Спасибо большое! Но тогда у меня из этого следует вопрос, как тогда связать между собой new input system и вот это нажатие на Button? Что я имею ввиду: у меня есть созданный inputAction, создана карта UI в ней action Click, создан автоматически создаваемый класс C#, сделал ещё один класс (крокладку), в котором слушаю ввод, внутри метод который указал  в UI карте OnClick, этот метод связан EventSystem на сцене и привязан к клику мышкой по ui объектам, без этой связки ui объекты не будут реагировать на нажатия, этот метод оставлять пустым и не обрабатывать его?

Новый Input System сам обрабатывает Event System, ничего делать не нужно и никакой Input Action для UI не нужен. А для Input Action на сцене нужен хотя бы один объект слушающий ввод и передающий его Input Asset, что бы он работал, не важно где.
